# Creating Thumbnails for Lightbox Images

Tags: thumbnails, lightbox

Can't for the life of me get my images to be thumbnails. Page is:

[www.aliceskids.org/kidswehelp2.html](http://www.aliceskids.org/kidswehelp2.html)

I have it calling:

```
#kidswehelp_images {
position: relative;
float: left;
width:  25px;
height: 25px;
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-repeat:   no-repeat;
background-size:     cover;}
```

Just trying to get the images to be sized the same so it's a lot neater.

[http://www.aliceskids.org/kidswehelp2.html]

```
  <a href="../images/thankyounotes/girl_clothing.jpg" data-lightbox="kidswehelp" data-title=""><img id="clothing" src="../images/thankyounotes/girl_clothing.jpg" class="myThumbs"></a>

    <a href="../images/thankyounotes/football_equipment.jpg" data-lightbox="kidswehelp" data-title=""><img id="football" src="../images/thankyounotes/football_equipment.jpg" class="myThumbs"></a>

    <a href="../images/thankyounotes/soccer_equipment.jpg" data-lightbox="kidswehelp" data-title=""><img id="soccer" src="../images/thankyounotes/soccer_equipment.jpg" class="myThumb"></a>

    <a href="../images/thankyounotes/maxx_clothing.jpg" data-lightbox="kidswehelp" data-title=""><img id="maxx" src="../images/thankyounotes/maxx_clothing.jpg" class="myThumb"></a>

    <a href="../images/thankyounotes/new_shoes.jpg" data-lightbox="kidswehelp" data-title=""><img id="newshoes" src="../images/thankyounotes/new_shoes.jpg" class="myThumb"></a>'
```

That's for the images.

This is from the stylesheet:

```
'.myThumbs {
float: left;
margin-right: 1%;
margin-bottom: 0.5em;
width: 50%;
height: 50%;}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are applying 25px to the whole div rather than the images themselves.

Give each image in that group a class like:

```
class="mythumbs"
```

then add the CSS

```
.myThumbs {
width:  25px;
height: 25px;
}
```

you can then remove your CSS for #kidswehelp_images

Comment: The images all have the same `id="thanks"`. You need to either give them each a unique id or use the class suggested above and remove the duplicate id's. Multiple items with the same class are fine but not the same id. Each id needs to be unique.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to call to the myThumbs class.

i moved everything from the "style" string to the CSS to clean it up, before even before that it wasn't referring to it.

`.myThumbs {
 float: left;
 margin-right: 1%;
 margin-bottom: 0.5em;
 width: 50%;
 height: 50%;}`

And this is the HTML for the image:

`<a href="../images/thankyounotes/girl_clothing.jpg" data-lightbox="kidswehelp" data-title=""><img id="clothing" src="../images/thankyounotes/girl_clothing.jpg" class="myThumbs"></a>`

Comment: Sadly, I did not.

Comment: Post your html page and CSS and I will take another look

Comment: Just added it to the original question.

The stylesheet code is without the ', also. Forgot to remove it from the post.